# Iterate keys of JSON object with same name suffixed with sequence number

Tags: dataweave

I have Json object like below where few elements (Score1, Score2..) are repeated with a sequence number suffixed to the element name. using dataweave 1.0, I need to iterate only these elements to check the values for a specific criteria.

I tried using mapObject but it is checking each key for the match. When the JSON is lengthy, this solution is not optimal.

```
{
  "Detail": {
  "Name": "Mark",
  "Team": "River Plate",
  "Score1": "01",
  "Score2": "07",
  "Score3": "11",
  "Score4": "00",
  "Score5": "03"
  "Description": "This is sample text",
  "Address": "Street 10"
}
}
```

Please help me with dataweave 1.0 script to iterate repeated elements like above.

Comment: What is your expected output ? As well can the other keys ( for .e.g. name, team etc)  present in the object contain numeric values in the name?

Comment: I need to search for a specific value in these set of elements and as of now no other elements contain numeric values in name.

Comment: Again given this input, what would the output be ? As a rule of thumb, always provide an input and a corresponding output in your ask.

Comment: I need to search these elements set (ScoreX) for specific values, say 70, 71. a true/false based on the search is what I need. I will use this search result in other part of flow.

Answer (score 1):

Considering DW 2.0, are you looking to achieve something like this, if yes we can work towards a DW 1.0 solution.

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.Detail filterObject  (($$) matches /\w+\d/) mapObject {
    (a: $) if ($== "70")
}
```

Output would be an empty object (for the input that you provided)  which means the value was not matched in the keys which had a word followed by a numeric value.

**Output**

```
{

}
```

Using DW 1.0 ,

**Script**

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
---
payload.Detail mapObject ({ ($$): $ } when (($$ matches /\w+\d/) and $ == "03" ) otherwise {})
```

**Output**

```
{
  "Score5": "03"
}
```

Which means that the input is filtered on keys which contain a word followed by a numeric and the corresponding value for that  key is "03" ( kept as "03" to show a result from the input that you provided. If you keep it as "70", this would give you an empty object) . Refer to [filter](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-operators#using-filter-on-an-object) use in DW1.0 over here.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your ask correctly, in your example you want to iterate only over the keys begining with 'Score'.In that case below script(DW 2.0) should be useful.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.Detail filterObject  (($$) startsWith("Score"))
```

You can apply your own logic on top of this as per your requirement.

[image]

Comment: I think Score was just a sample field and it could be any key with a numeric value at the end. As well the solution that he is expecting is in DW1.0

Comment: As well the keys identified should have a value ("70" or "71" in this case) for them to show up in the final response or else it should be empty.